# Ajax automatically placing double quotes around variable data returned in success call

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, chart.js

I'm trying to build a chartjs horizontal bar chart using Ajax in an MVC application. Everytime the data returns, it places double quotes around the data returned from the variables.

My code:

```
**<script>
    $("#charts").click(function () {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: rootDir + "Usd/provStDtAll",
                dataType: 'json',
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                timeout: 30000,
                data: {},
                success: function (adata) {
                    var sDate = '';
                    var ooSum = '';
                    var bgC = '';
                    for (var i = 0; i < adata.length; i++) {
                        sDate += '"' + adata[i].startDate + '",';
                        ooSum += adata[i].oSum + ',';
                        bgC += '"' + adata[i].bgcolor + '",';

                    }

                    console.log(sDate);
                    console.log(ooSum);
                    console.log(bgC);
                    
                    var ctx = document.getElementById('psdChart').getContext('2d');
                    var chart1 = new Chart(ctx, {
                        type: 'horizontalBar',
                        data: {
                            labels: [sDate],
                            datasets: [
                                {
                                    label: 'Start Date',
                                    backgroundColor: [bgC],
                                    data: [ooSum]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        options: {
                            responsive: true,
                            scales: {
                                yAxes: [{
                                    display: true,
                                    ticks: { beginAtZero: true }
                                }],
                                xAxes: [{
                                    display: true,
                                    ticks: { beginAtZero: true }
                                }]
                            },
                            legend: { display: false },
                            title: {
                                display: true,
                                text: 'Providers by Start Date'
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    chart1.render();        

                }
            });
    
    });
</script>**
```

In specific the variables of "sDate", "bgC", and "ooSum" are all enclosed in double quotes. The results are as follows:

```
**sDate = ""Nov 2020","Mar 2021","Jan 2021","Feb 2021","Dec 2020","Apr 2021","
bgC = ""#00437d","#00437d","#00437d","#00437d","#00437d","#00437d","
ooSum = "1,57,18,26,1,9,"**
```

This causes the chart not to render correctly as all the data is enclosed in quotes.

I'd like the variable to return something like this...

```
**sDate = "Nov 2020","Mar 2021","Jan 2021","Feb 2021","Dec 2020","Apr 2021",
bgC = "#00437d","#00437d","#00437d","#00437d","#00437d","#00437d",
ooSum = 1,57,18,26,1,9,**
```

What am I doing incorrectly??? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:

The controller is as follows...

```
[HttpPost]
   public JsonResult provStDtAll()
   {
      
      var psdAll = (from a in _signalContext.tIList.AsEnumerable()
                    where a.StartDate != null
          group a by new { StartDate = String.Format("{0:MMM yyyy}", 
          a.StartDate) } into b
                orderby b.Key.StartDate descending
                select new { b.Key.StartDate, oSum = b.Count(), bgcolor = 
     "#00437d" }).ToList();
 
    return Json(psdAll);
    }
```

And console.log(adata) returns the following...

```
Array(6)
0: {startDate: "Nov 2020", oSum: 1, bgcolor: "#00437d"}
1: {startDate: "Mar 2021", oSum: 57, bgcolor: "#00437d"}
2: {startDate: "Jan 2021", oSum: 18, bgcolor: "#00437d"}
3: {startDate: "Feb 2021", oSum: 26, bgcolor: "#00437d"}
4: {startDate: "Dec 2020", oSum: 1, bgcolor: "#00437d"}
5: {startDate: "Apr 2021", oSum: 9, bgcolor: "#00437d"}
length: 6
__proto__: Array(0)
concat: ƒ concat()
constructor: ƒ Array()
copyWithin: ƒ copyWithin()
entries: ƒ entries()
every: ƒ every()
fill: ƒ fill()
filter: ƒ filter()
find: ƒ find()
findIndex: ƒ findIndex()
flat: ƒ flat()
flatMap: ƒ flatMap()
forEach: ƒ forEach()
includes: ƒ includes()
indexOf: ƒ indexOf()
join: ƒ join()
keys: ƒ keys()
lastIndexOf: ƒ lastIndexOf()
length: 0
map: ƒ map()
pop: ƒ pop()
push: ƒ push()
reduce: ƒ reduce()
reduceRight: ƒ reduceRight()
reverse: ƒ reverse()
shift: ƒ shift()
slice: ƒ slice()
some: ƒ some()
sort: ƒ sort()
splice: ƒ splice()
toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()
toString: ƒ toString()
unshift: ƒ unshift()
values: ƒ values()
Symbol(Symbol.iterator): ƒ values()
Symbol(Symbol.unscopables): {copyWithin: true, entries: true, fill: true, find: true, findIndex: true, …}
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Maybe stop enclosing the data in quotes... you are doing this with your code. What output you are expecting?

Comment: The issue is that the double quotes enclose the entire string. In the case of the oSum variable, I'm  not placing any quotes in that variable yet double quotes appear after running.

Comment: Could you show your controller jsonresult provStDtAll?

Comment: Can you show the results of this: console.log(adata), including the property results of this odata. If these are array results, please show the results.

Comment: Thanks @Adlorem and Willy for giving this a look! It's had me stumped. I'm thinking that it has something to do with when and how I'm calling the variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code I think you need to define array not string for your variables. Example:

```
                var sDate = [];
                var ooSum = [];
                var bgC = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < adata.length; i++) {
                    sDate.push(adata[i].startDate);
                    ooSum.push(adata[i].oSum);
                    bgC.push(adata[i].bgcolor);

                }
```

then replace

```
                    data: {
                        labels: sDate,
                        datasets: [
                            {
                                label: 'Start Date',
                                backgroundColor: bgC,
                                data: ooSum
                            }
                        ]
                    },
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help on this! This worked like a charm as soon as I pasted it in.

Comment: Glad I could help.